# Microsoft Access insert query

Tags: ms-access, vba

Access table `Allowances_3_15_18` has 5 columns.  I want to insert a calculated field from a form `EmployeeSalary)` into one of the columns `Amount` in the table.

Each value will link with the relevant primary ID's from the form and the table which are the same `JobID`. How do I do this in VBA?

I currently have done it in the `afterUpdate` event in the property sheet.

```
Private Sub ProjectedDollarAmount_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ProjectedDollarAmount As Currency

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Allowances_3_15_18] ([Amount]) VALUES (" & _
        PrepareSQLNumber(Me.ProjectedDollarAmount) & ") WHERE JobID = " & _
        PrepareSQLNumber(Me.JobID) & ";"

    Call ExecuteMyCommand(strSQL)
End Sub
```

Comment: What  is, and what isn't working? Do you just want to ask how to execute SQL strings in the current database from VBA?

Comment: Hi Erik, The query isnt working at all. I have defaulted the value in the table to 0, but it seems the insert query is not being called and I cant figure out why. Each time I load the table and the form, the value continues to be 0. Instead of the dollar amount it is showing on the form ($ 10, 000)

Comment: Then please try to provide a [mcve]. Include the code to `PrepareSQLNumber` and `ExecuteMyCommand`. Print out that SQL string before you're executing it. Include any other relevant details.

Comment: Allowances_3_15_18 has 4 columns, JobID, JobName, EmployeeName, Amount. It has 803 records. these 803 records represent a different job, and I have a form EmployeeSalary which displays each of the 803 jobs when I click on each relevant job. When EmployeeSalary loads it calculates the amount figure based on a number of figures, but only in the form. I want to store this figure in my table. I hope this answers your question as I am unsure as to what you mean when you say you need a M, C and V example. All the code is visible there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get away from SQL concatenation and start using parameters.

Create a query with two parameters, the amount to be inserted and the JobId. The query's SQL should be something like this:

```
PARAMETERS [prmAmount] Currency, [prmJobId] Long;
UPDATE [Allowances_3_15_18] SET [Amount] = [prmAmount]
WHERE JobID = [prmJobId];
```

Then in code, simply pass the parameter values and execute the above query:

```
Sub Add()
    With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qryName")
        .Parameters("[prmAmount]").Value = PrepareSQLNumber(Me.ProjectedDollarAmount)
        .Parameters("[prmJobId]").Value = PrepareSQLNumber(Me.JobID)
        .Execute dbFailOnError
    End With
End Sub
```

You need to change the `qryName` to the actual name of the query.

You can read more about parameter queries [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed).

Comment: You'd likely want to ditch those prepares, but I don't have a clue what they're doing (since OP didn't provide the code for them like I asked). Usually, prepare functions turn things into strings with appropriate formatting and delimiters, and that's not desirable when using them as a parameter. Note that to use parameters, you don't have to save the query.

Comment: I thought of that but maybe they're some sort of calculation functions, I don't know. The OP can decide. As for the query, since it will be reused over time let it be there. It's easier to maintain.